# Why isn't the restart command working for Jenkins node in Groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to reboot nodes that are under a master node in Jenkins using Groovy. However, the reboot isn't working and it's only taking the nodes offline and then bringing them back online.  Why isn't the reboot command working?  Am I missing something?  This is what I currently have:

```
Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
def jenkins_Nodes = jenkins.getNodes()

for (Node node in jenkins_Nodes) {
    if(node.name == "some computer name") {
       node.getComputer().setAcceptingTasks(false);
       while(true) {
         if(node.getComputer().countBusy() == 0) {
            def restart = "shutdown /r /f".execute();
            restart.waitFor();
            break;
         }
       }
       node.getComputer().launch();
       node.getComputer().setAcceptingTasks(true);
     }
    //other computers
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `shutdown` command is not executed on the remote node. **You need to delegate the execution of `shutdown` to the remote node**.

It's relatively easy to do via `RemotingDiagnostics` -- with that, your sample looks like this:

```
import hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics

restart_script = '''
"shutdown /r /f".execute()
'''

Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
def jenkins_Nodes = jenkins.getNodes()

for (Node node in jenkins_Nodes) {
    if(node.name == "some computer name") {
       node.getComputer().setAcceptingTasks(false);
       while(true) {
         if(node.getComputer().countBusy() == 0) {
            result = RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(restart_script, node.channel)
            break;
         }
       }
       node.getComputer().launch();
       node.getComputer().setAcceptingTasks(true);
     }
    //other computers
}
```

Comment: Does this wait for the restart to complete or would I have to give it some time to reboot?

Comment: Also, why isn’t the node going offline and instead the connection breaks?

Comment: No, your current code won't wait for completion. The connection breaks because the slave will reboot while the connection is active. This will be difficult to fix -- if you disconnected the node yourself beforehand, then you wouldn't be able to send the shutdown command (you could work around this by starting shutdown in background and adding some delay, but I wouldn't know how to do that on Windows).

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense. Would this also work on Windows 7 machines?